# I want to include a scripting language in C++ project. Lua vs Bison/Yacc

Tags: c++, lua, bison, dsl, yacc

I want to implement a scripting language in my app. Just for controlling some behavior, defining rules etc.

I haven't found a reason to use Lua over bison/yacc or vice-versa. What are advantages and disadvantages of these tools?

From implementation point Lua seems to be much easier to implement while yacc/bison requires to learn to write parser markup but then I have a standalone parser. Other than that what are the differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're completely different things, and not really comparable. Lua is an (embeddable) scripting language, Bison/yacc something you could write a lexer and parser for a language with.

With Bison/Yacc, you would still have to implement the actual execution engine (VM, whatever) for your scripting language.

So if you want a scripting language embedded in your app, lua gives you one "out of the box". Bison/yacc give you (some of ) the tools for implementing one.

If you do want a parser for some reason, you can use bison/yacc, or you might want to look at lpeg in Lua, depending on your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for lpeg for lua. So basically I would want to use bison/yacc for a custom syntax which I need for some reason instead of having one out of the box(lua)?

Comment: Depends on your syntax requirements. You could write something in lpeg that "compiled" to Lua. Or you could do that in bison/yacc. Or you could use bison/yacc and an interpreter in C++. In any case, if you use bison/yacc, you have to do some implementation that can actually execute something. Lua's origins were in "executing" things that looked like data - references- and so it's quite well suited to managing configurations/rules. You can have a syntax that looks quite declarative but is actually lua.

Comment: And I might add that learning bison/flex is a valuable exercise in itself, knowing those tools makes you a better programmer.

Comment: Maybe. I have used them (I have written compilers for food) but I've not used them or anything similar in 10+ years. Learning some parsing theory and practical tools is a Good Thing, though.